# How to dynamically bind an existing OpenUI5 Combobox?

Tags: sapui5

I'm evaluating OpenUI5 and I'm not clear about the binding concept.

In a XML login view, I have a Combobox that I want to populate after a successful login:

```
<ComboBox id="cboJoraniInstance" enabled="false" />
```

So, into my controller I've created an Ajax call with a parameter:

```
return Controller.extend("sap.ui.jorani.wt.controller.Login", {
    onCheckEmail : function () {
    var oDialog = this.getView().byId("BusyDialog");
        oDialog.open();
        var sMail = this.getView().byId("txtEmail").getValue();
        var oListInst = this.getView().byId("cboJoraniInstance");
        var aData = jQuery.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost/dummy/getJoraniInstances.php',
            data: {
                mail: sMail
            },
            async: false,
            success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //Link Combobox
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                oModel.setData(data);
                oListInst.setModel(oModel);
                oListInst.bindElement("/Instances");
                oListInst.bindProperty("value", "Url");
                oListInst.bindProperty("name", "name");
                oListInst.setEnabled();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                MessageToast.show('An error occured');
            }
        });
        oDialog.close();
    },
```

});

The call to my web service is OK and returns:

```
{
    "Instances": [{
        "Name": "Local",
        "IsDefault": true,
        "Url": "http:\/\/localhost\/jorani\/"
    }, {
        "Name": "D\u00e9mo",
        "IsDefault": false,
        "Url": "https:\/\/demo.jorani.org\/"
    }]
}
```

The code executes without error, but the control is not filled by my binding attempts.

I've checked the various SO questions on this topic and they all add a new ComboBox into the view dynamically, for example:

```
oListInst.placeAt("content");
```

But that is not what I want to achieve, I'd like to fill an existing object. Is it possible?

Concerning the view, if I fill the Combobox with the code below, it is working fine (but it doesn't use the binding feature):

```
$.each(data.Instances, function(i, obj) {
    oListInst.addItem(new sap.ui.core.ListItem({key:obj.Url, text:obj.Name}));
});
```

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: @Marc it is an XML view (<mvc:View...</mvc:View>) and I gave the declaration of the Combobox in my question. I edited the question so as to explain that it doesn't come from a invalid view, because I can add the items one by one (without binding). Are you sure that the complete view would help to answer?

Comment: I suggest using a template for a single item (thats why I wanted to see the view) and then doing the binding directly in the view (see here: https://openui5beta.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ComboBox/code) or using `bindItems` in your code (instead of `bindElement`)